# How to show the result of NetworkX graph in Plotly.Dash using Dash callbacks

Tags: python, graph, networkx, plotly-dash, graph-visualization

I have a list of edges between several nodes of a graph as a `.csv` file. I am reading the mentioned file and storing it in a Dash `Store` component like below:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
del dataset[dataset.columns[0]]
return  html.Div(className="mx-auto text-center", children=[
dcc.Store(id="approach-1-dataset",  data=dataset.to_dict('records'))]
```

Then using `NetworkX` the graph is created after the user clicks on a button in the view like below:

```
@app.callback(Output('visualization-container', 'children'),
          Input('visualize-button', 'n_clicks'),
          State('dataset', 'data'))
def visualize_graph(n1,dataset):
    if n1:
        main_dataset = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataset)
        pd.set_option('precision',10)
        G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(main_dataset, 'member1', 'member2', create_using = nx.Graph())
        nodes = G.nodes()
        degree = G.degree()
        colors = [degree[n] for n in nodes]
        size = [(degree[n]) for n in nodes]
        pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)
        pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k = 0.2)
        cmap = plt.cm.viridis_r
        cmap = plt.cm.Greys
        fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,9), dpi=100)
        nx.draw(G,pos,alpha = 0.8, nodelist = nodes, node_color = colors, node_size = size , with_labels= False,font_size = 6, width = 0.2, cmap = cmap, edge_color ='yellow')
        fig.set_facecolor('#0B243B')
        return dcc.Graph(figure = fig)
    return ""
```

Using this code I get the following error in my view:

> Callback error updating visualization-container.children

> dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for `<Output` visualization-container.children`>` returned a value having type
> `Graph` which is not JSON serializable. The value in question is
> either the only value returned, or is in the top level of the returned
> list, and has string representation `Graph(figure=<Figure size 1500x900 with 1 Axes>)` In general, Dash properties can only be dash
> components, strings, dictionaries, numbers, None, or lists of those.

And this error in my console:

> Assertion failed: (NSViewIsCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay() != currentlyBuildingLayerTree), function NSViewSetCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay, file NSView.m, line 13477.

It is worth mentioning that the same code works pretty fine when I run it directly in a Jupyter notebook but when I try to run it in a dash call back and return the result as a `dcc.Graph` component I get the errors.

How can I solve this issue?

My `.csv` file looks like below:

member1,member2,weight

200114206,3949436,1

217350178,8539046,1

.

.

.

193986670,8539046,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the figure to a base64-encoded object, which you can display as an html-image in dash. Try the snippet below for a working example.

But if you want to work with a 'graph' as in network-graph, don't use Dcc.Graph, but use cyto.Cytoscape. See https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import base64

dataset = [
    (200114206,3949436,1),
    (217350178,8539046,1)
]

main_dataset = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=["member1" ,"member2", "weight"])
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(main_dataset, 'member1', 'member2', create_using = nx.Graph())
nodes = G.nodes()
degree = G.degree()
colors = [degree[n] for n in nodes]
size = [(degree[n]) for n in nodes]
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k = 0.2)
cmap = plt.cm.Greys
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,9), dpi=100)
nx.draw(G, pos, alpha=0.8, nodelist=nodes, node_color=colors, node_size=size, with_labels=False, font_size=6, width=0.2, cmap=cmap, edge_color ='yellow')
fig.set_facecolor('#0B243B')

buffer = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buffer, format="jpg")
buffer.seek(0)
base64_encoded_image = base64.b64encode(buffer.read()).decode('utf-8')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Button(id="visualisation_button", children="click me"),
    html.Div(id="visualisation_block")
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("visualisation_block", "children")
    ,Input("visualisation_button", "n_clicks"))
def update_vis(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks:

        base64_encoded_image
        return html.Img(id=f'nxplot_img',
                 src=f'data:image/png;base64, {base64_encoded_image}',
                 style = {'height': '50%', 'width': "50%"}
                 )

app.run_server()
```